# How to make a thank you html page accessible only after form submission

Tags: html, forms, validation, registration

I have a plain standalone HTML page with a regular HTML form, where the action is to send registrants' details to our email marketing system. Once they submit the form they get taken to another really simple HTML page where there is a thank you message and a file download. Is it at all possible to make the thank you page only accessible if proceeded to from the registration page? I'm not sure if this is a logical question, since there is no login or a database involved. I am also new to this so forgive me if it's a silly question! Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: HTML alone cannot do this, what web programming language are you using to handle the form submit? (PHP, Java, etc.)

Comment: _Something_ on the server is handling that form. It could be rewritten to handle this task also.

Comment: The form is handled externally - the action in the HTML form is a URL, which is generated by an email marketing platform, so all validation happens within that platform as that's where the registrants' details will go on submission. It's all hard-coded so all I can set there is where to proceed if the form submitted is valid, which is the thank oyu page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which page the user came from using [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer), and execute some JavaScript code based on that - such as redirecting them away from the page if it's not where you expect them to be coming from.

Keep in mind that it's JavaScript so it can be disabled and is not a guarantee of preventing people from seeing the page. You'll need some proper server-side code to do that. Also keep in mind if they go directly to that page (such as typing it in the url) document.referrer is empty.

```
if(document.referrer != 'http://yourwebsite.com/form.html') 
   window.location = 'http://yourwebsite.com';
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm not too worried about it working in every single case but it's better than nothing. So what this does is redirect the person to the website, if they didn't get to the page from the form page? Can this be inserted in the head of the thank you page to work?

Comment: Yes - you'll want to put it anywhere (such as in the <head>) on the thank you page, enclosed in <script></script> tags. As it's JavaScript the page will have to load and the code executed before they are redirected - so it will not be as smooth as a server-side redirect, but if you don't have access to that this is a possible solution.